# How to execute a user loop with shortcode

Tags: loop

i am trying to create a membership directory that will display all the user which would be trigger by a shortcode based on the user ID.

I am not sure what is wrong with the code I did

```
my_members = get_the_author_meta('ID');
while ( !empty (my_members) ) : 
echo do_shortcode('[li_profile id='. my_members . ']');
endwhile:
```

I am not asking how to create the shortcode because the shortcode works by default doing something like this on a regular page
[li_profile id=1] to display user data with User ID 1

the loop I need would be to loop the shortcode like below

[li_profile id=1]

[li_profile id=2]

[li_profile id=3]

[li_profile id=4]

[li_profile id=5]

[li_profile id=6]

until there are user ID available

Comment: And where is the code that represents `[li_profile]` into something?

Comment: `get_the_author_meta` retrieves the user meta of the author, not a list of users, and that loop has no exit condition, it will always run ( and there's no `$` on my_members so it's got PHP syntax errors

Comment: I'd recommend asking an additional question on the site on how to display a list of users, another question on how to create a basic shortcode, then combine those answers

Comment: i have updated my question